# How to create content on the fly and add it to the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I can create a content and add it the DOM like this:

```
var $div = $('<div />');
$div.attr('id', 'my-awesome-div');
```

This div is created and added to the DOM as it can be seen when you inspect the page but will not show when you view page source. Is there any way to create a content on the fly in a way that it can be shown in the source code as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Inspect element" - shows the current state of the DOM, **including dynamically generated elements**. "View source" - shows only the **original DOM**, which was created by the page's html output (without dynamic elements).

> Is there any way to create a content on the fly in a way that it can
>   be shown in the source code as well?

Having that said, **dynamic content** can also be generated by Server-Side languages such as PHP, Java etc.

Comment: Yeah thought of that but I am creating a widget users will use on their website and I have no control on their server to use PHP or Java. Thanks for the explanantion.

Comment: If that's the case, the widget will not appear on their source code. Why do you need it to appear there?

Comment: It is a google rich snippet that is created on the fly. Google is not able to read it so my guess is that it is because the div does not show in the source code

Comment: Yeah... the bots won't read it today. Who knows, maybe sooner than later they'll start reading JS dynamic content too.

Answer (score 2):

You can't unless you use a developing tool like Firebug for Firefox or the inspector of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

View Page Source will only show you the static contents of the file being shown.
Inspect elemnet will show you all the dynamically generated elements as well.

Also, a shorthand method to do the same is as follows,

```
var $div = $('<div />',{'id':'my-awesome-div'});
```

Answer (score 2):

**`Is there any way to create a content on the fly in a way that it can be shown in the source code as well?`**

The simple answer is

## NO

The page source is created the first time and it doesn't change